# How to show "success" message after operation was done successfully

Tags: c#, messagebox

Im using MVS Community 2015. I can't figure out how to make this happen. I want to do as follows: to show a short message after user pressed a button. I don't want it be like MessageBox so you have to click OK, just a little text that maybe dissapears in 3 seconds. Is that possible somehow?
Piece of code:

```
if (lastRbOperation != GetRbInfo())  // if(true) -> success
            {
                File.AppendAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, GetRbInfo() + ". Результат:\n", Encoding.UTF8);
                File.AppendAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Convert.ToString(txtResult.Text) + "\n\n");
                lastRbOperation = GetRbInfo();
                // show the message("Data was saved successfully").
            }
```

Comment: There is no built-in functionality for that. You can implement it yourself, however. Make a form with `BorderStyle = None` and use a `Timer` to countdown 3 seconds.

Comment: Create a custom `Dialog` or `Form` or any other window that once shown runs a timer and after so much time closes the window. Easiest done with a dialog box because if you call `ShowDialog` it will close when its result is set

Comment: I did it with new `Form` and `Timer`. Perfect. Thanks for advices.